# How would I print the largest possible float and double in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, printf, limits

For the following code,

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("double max = %??\n", DBL_MAX);
    printf("double min = %??\n", DBL_MIN);
    printf("double epsilon  = %??\n", DBL_EPSILON);
    printf("float epsilon  = %??\n", FLT_EPSILON);
    printf("float max = %??\n", FLT_MAX);
    printf("float min = %??\n\n", FLT_MIN);
    return 0;
}
```

what specifiers would I have to use in place of the ??'s in order for printf to display the various quantities as appropriately-sized decimal numbers?

Comment: Read a man page and do some experiments. For example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: @CharlieBurns: No, `float` is promoted to `double`, so the same format (`%f`, `%e`, or `%g`) is used for both.

Comment: @AdamBurry: cppreference.com is generally considered better than cplusplus.com: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: @KeithThompson, thank you for the tip. I will check it out.

Comment: `DBL_MAX` is the largest _finite_ `double`.  `INFINITY` is a tad larger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the same format you'd use for any other values of those types:

```c
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("FLT_MAX = %g\n", FLT_MAX);
    printf("DBL_MAX = %g\n", DBL_MAX);
    printf("LDBL_MAX = %Lg\n", LDBL_MAX);
}
```

Arguments of type `float` are promoted to `double` for variadic functions like `printf`, which is why you use the same format for both.

`%f` prints a floating-point value using decimal notation with no exponent, which will give you a very long string of (mostly insignificant) digits for very large values.

`%e` forces the use of an exponent.

`%g` uses either `%f` or `%e`, depending on the magnitude of the number being printed.

On my system, the above prints the following:

```c
FLT_MAX = 3.40282e+38
DBL_MAX = 1.79769e+308
LDBL_MAX = 1.18973e+4932
```

As Eric Postpischil points out in a comment, the above prints only approximations of the values. You can print more digits by specifying a precision (the number of digits you'll need depends on the precision of the types); for example, you can replace `%g` by `%.20g`.

Or, if your implementation supports it, C99 added the ability to print floating-point values in hexadecimal with as much precision as necessary:

```c
printf("FLT_MAX = %a\n", FLT_MAX);
printf("DBL_MAX = %a\n", DBL_MAX);
printf("LDBL_MAX = %La\n", LDBL_MAX);
```

But the result is not as easily human-readable as the usual decimal format:

```
FLT_MAX = 0x1.fffffep+127
DBL_MAX = 0x1.fffffffffffffp+1023
LDBL_MAX = 0xf.fffffffffffffffp+16380
```

(Note: `main()` is an obsolescent definition; use `int main(void)` instead.)

Comment: This does not actually do what the question asked, as it does not print the largest possible values, just approximations of them. And those approximations are insufficient to represent the proper values when converted back from decimal to their floating-point types. Apple GCC 4.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 will print the complete, exact values if a sufficient precision is added to the specifier.

Comment: `%f` will give you the exact values on a decent implementation.

Comment: @R..: Sure, if you don't mind nearly 5000 digits (depending on the actual precision) for `LDB_MAX`.

Comment: Recommend against using `%f` with DBL_EPSILON in OP post, as it results in an unhelpful "0.000000".

Answer (score 1):

To print approximations of the maximums with enough digits to represent the actual values (the result of converting the printed value back to floating-point should be the original value), you can use:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    printf("%.*g\n", DECIMAL_DIG, FLT_MAX);
    printf("%.*g\n", DECIMAL_DIG, DBL_MAX);
    printf("%.*Lg\n", DECIMAL_DIG, LDBL_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

In C 2011, you can use the more specific `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG`, `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`, and `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` in place of `DECIMAL_DIG`.

To print the exact values, instead of approximations, you need to specify more precision. `(int) (log10(x)+1)` digits should be enough.

Approximations of the minimums and the epsilons can be printed with sufficient accuracy in the same way. However, calculating the numbers of digits needed for exact values may be more complicated than for the maximums. (Technically, it may be impossible in exotic C implementations. E.g., a base-three floating-point system would have a minimum not representable in any finite number of decimal digits. I am not aware of any such implementations in use.)

Comment: +1 for using `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` rather than `DBL_DIG`.  The first is best for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the last three prints in my solution to the exercise 2.1 from The C Programming Language

```
// float or IEEE754 binary32
printf(
    "float: {min: %e, max: %e}, comp: {min: %e, max: %e}\n",
    FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX, pow(2,-126), pow(2,127) * (2 - pow(2,-23))
    );
// double or IEEE754 binary64
printf(
    "double: {min: %e, max: %e}, comp: {min: %e, max: %e}\n",
    DBL_MIN, DBL_MAX, pow(2,-1022), pow(2,1023) * (2 - pow(2,-52))
    );
// long double or IEEE754 binary 128
printf(
    "long double: {min: %Le, max: %Le}, comp: {min: %Le, max: %Le}\n",
    LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX, powl(2,-16382), powl(2,16383) * (2 - powl(2,-112))
    );
```

Obviously, the maximal values are calculated according to IEEE 754. The full solution is available via link:
https://github.com/mat90x/tcpl/blob/master/types_ranges.c