# Which specifier to use to print the max/min value of long double?

Tags: c, types, floating-point, printf, format-specifiers

As a new C programming learner, I'm trying to understand which specifier I should use in printf to display the maximum and minimum values of a long double type. Per the following StackOverflow answer, I can use %Lg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18797417/1536240

But that doesn't seem to do the trick. I've tried %e, %f, %Lf, %g and %Lg, but it's not working. Here's the relevant part of my code I'm having issues with (the rest of the stuff I'm doing's working fine):

```
printf("**long double**\nStorage size: %d bytes \t Minimum value: %Lg 
\t Maximum value: %Lg\n", sizeof(long double), LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX);
```

I've included these header files at the top:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>
```

I'm kinda lost here.

**EDIT:** Sorry for not explaining what the output is. I'm using %Lg right now, and I'm getting this in the terminal.

[image: my output]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problem you have? Do you get build errors or warnings? Which ones? Do you get unexpected results? Then what is the expected and actual outputs? Something else?

Comment: what's your compiler & version? some format specifiers are sometimes missing

Comment: Define "it's not working".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, I've updated my question and added a screenshot!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm using CodeBlocks, mingw32-gcc.exe. Does that help?

Comment: doesn't matter now. Both answers below explain your issue

Comment: What is the result if code does **not** try to print the size? `printf("**long double**\nMinimum value: %Lg 
\t Maximum value: %Lg\n", LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX);`?

Comment: @chux I get the expected result when I take off sizeof(). Thanks for that workaround. But then now I need to find a way to add back sizeof() without having messed up min/max values for the `long double` type. Unfortunately, the `%zu` specifier suggested in other comments actually prints the string "zu" as the output.

Comment: @IsaacAsante-- Microsoft C compilers took a long time to join the party and support the `%zu` directive. You could try `%lu` to print an `unsigned long` value. To be safe, you should probably cast the result of `sizeof` to `(unsigned long)`: `printf("**long double**\nStorage size: %lu bytes \t Minimum value: %Lg \t Maximum value: %Lg\n", (unsigned long) sizeof(long double), LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX);`

Comment: Actually, you can just cast the result of the `sizeof` operator, because to be compatible with Microsoft stuff (LLP64 data model!) you'd actually need to use `unsigned long long`  – the largest unsigned integer type (but only available in C99 and later), and the type corresponding to `size_t` on LLP64 data model. In other words, use `printf("**long double**\n\tStorage size: %d\n\tMinimum value: %.60Lg\n\tMaximum value: %.60Lg\n", (int) sizeof (long double), (long double)LDBL_MIN, (long double)LDBL_MAX);` (The `(long double)` casts are a belt-and-suspenders approach; most likely unnecessary.)

Comment: To print the size, without using `%zu`, cast to a wide unsigned type.  `printf("Storage size: %llu bytes\n", (unsigned long long) sizeof(long double));` or in this case, since the since of a double will be small `printf("Storage size: %u bytes\n", (unsigned) sizeof(long double));`

Answer (score 7):

While you should provide the obtained results in your question, your mistake likely is to use `%d` to print the result of `sizeof`, which should be printed with `%zu`.

This causes undefined behavior. For some platforms, the rest of `printf`'s arguments, on the stack, will be misinterpreted because the width of `int` does not match the width of `size_t`.

Comment: Sorry, I've added a screenshot of my output now!

Comment: Adding that screenshot does not change the validity of this excellent answer.

Comment: Actually, my problem here isn't the output of `sizeof()`. It's the output for the specifier for `LDBL_MIN` and `LDBL_MAX`.

Comment: @IsaacAsante - of course but `%d` is used to calculate the position of the next argument on the stack. So it calculates the wrong location (4 bytes off) for the next 2 `%Lg` arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `"%Lf"` or `"%Lg"` for a `long double`, and `%zu` (since and including C99) for the `sizeof` return type `size_t`.

Currently the behaviour of your program is *undefined*: `%d` is not appropriate for a `size_t` type.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Anyway, on my PC, when I compile in CodeBlocks, it's still showing wrong output for max/min values like in the screenshot I added to my question. But I just tried with an online IDE at CodeChef.com and there's no issue. I assume the issue is at my end.